# ¿Como importar un archivo excel a SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Que tal quisiera saber si existe la manera de importar un excel a SQL server, lo que hice fue meterme a correos de México para exportar todos los códigos postales de México, ya que los voy a consumir en un Web API, pero sería mucho trabajo hacer insert por insert, las opciones en las que puedo descargar los códigos postales es en Excel, TXT, XML. Adjunto la imagen de como se visualiza el excel.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes usar sqlldr a partir de un CSV

Comment: ¿Conoces SSIS (Integration Services)?

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de hacer ese trabajo un poco más dinámico es que construyas las query de insert siempre en excel.

[image: Construcción de query desde excel]

[image: En la columna "A"]

Te llevará un poco de tiempo pero es una forma viable de hacerlo.
Ejemplo:
INSERT INTO GLB_MUNICIPIOS (CD_DEPTO, DS_NOMBRE_MUNICIPIO, USUA_CREA) VALUES (

Luego ya vas agregando los campos que requiere tu tabla. Para posteriormente concatenar.
Lo que resta es copiar toda la columna "A" y pegar eso en una nueva query con la base de datos seleccionada para ejecutar la inserción.
Importante, por buena práctica, al final de cada insert debe de ir ";"

Comment: no se si sea la manera correcta ya que son mas de 100 mil registros :(

Comment: Existen muchas maneras de hacer esto. [Importar con openRowSet](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/05/09/importar-desde-excel-con-openrowset/). Otra manera [Importar con el asistente](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/09/02/importar-desde-excel-a-sql-server-facil-y-rapido/)